# Function body defined in /etc/profile appears in shell history on login

Tags: shell, aix, profile

We run IBM AIX here (currently 7100-03-03-1415) that is missing a fair amount of the utility preset in other versions of UNIX.  One of the things that we need to do on a semi-regular basis is convert from epoch time to a standard timestamp.  To solve this problem, I created this function and placed it in `/etc/profile`:

```
## Functions that are useful enough to be inherited by everyone ##
# Prints timestamp from epoch time
epoch() {

        if [ $# -eq 1 ] ; then
                SECONDS="$1"
        elif [ -t 0 ] || [ $# -gt 1 ] ; then
                echo "Usage: epoch <timestamp>"
                return 127
        else
                read SECONDS
        fi

        perl -e 'print scalar localtime $ARGV[0],"\n"' $SECONDS
        return 0
}
```

The function takes either an argument or reads from `stdin` and prints the converted timestamp.

Since pushing this function to all of our LPARs for use across the board, I've noticed that the text of the function is appearing in every users' `.sh_history` after spawning a new shell:

```
ls -la
ssh localhost

        if [ $# -eq 1 ] ; then
                SECONDS="$1"
        elif [ -t 0 ] || [ $# -gt 1 ] ; then
                echo "Usage: epoch <timestamp>"
                return 127
        else
                read SECONDS
        fi

        perl -e 'print scalar localtime $ARGV[0],"\n"' $SECONDS
        return 0
}
cat .sh_history
```

I've never seen anything like this before.  It's not affecting production or uptime, so this is more of a curiosity than anything else.  It's obvious that the function is being read when loading the user's shell, but what would be causing this to print to the shell history?

Edited to add:  Currently running ksh version M-11/16/88f.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually intended behavior; ksh automatically logs all function definitions in the history file.

This option can be turned off with the "nolog" option: `set -o nolog`